# Delete duplicates in a single dataset relative to another one in C#

Tags: c#, blueprism

I'm new to C#. 
Trying to remove duplicates in CollectionIn1 but it doesn't work. No duplicates are removed in CollectionIn.

Just to clarify, the collectionIn has [A,B,C,D] and collectionIn2 has [A,B,C].

So i want to remove the values (A,B,C) in collectionIn

```
for (int i = 0; i < CollectionIn.Rows.Count; i++) {
    string value1 = CollectionIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower(); 

    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < CollectionIn2.Rows.Count; i2++) {
        string value2 = CollectionIn2.Rows[i2].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower(); 

        if (value1 == value2) {
            //Remove value1 when value1 == value2
            CollectionIn.Rows[i].Delete(); <--- Trying to delete when there is duplicate in both collections

            CollectionIn.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
    //CollectionOut.Rows.Add(value1);
}
```

I made some changes from this link
http://www.rpaforum.net/threads/how-to-compare-two-excel-sheet-using-c-code-in-blueprism.897/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing two sets can have a complexity of O(n2). This is bad. You can get improve on that if you have an initial hash lookup.

```
var Set1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

//Prehash all values in the set that won't be deleted from 
for (int i = 0; i < CollectionIn.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string value1 = CollectionIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower();
    Set1.Add(value1, i);
}

//Loop over the other set
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < CollectionIn2.Rows.Count; i2++)
{
    string value2 = CollectionIn2.Rows[i2].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower();

    int foundIndex;
    if (Set1.TryGetValue(value2, out foundIndex) == false)
        continue;

    //Remove value1 when value1 == value2
    CollectionIn.Rows[foundIndex].Delete();
}
CollectionIn.AcceptChanges(); //It's probably best to save changes last as a single call
```

I *hashed* CollectionIn, and then *iterated* CollectionIn2. This means I needed a dictionary so I would have the CollectionIn index for deleting. If this was reversed, and CollectionIn2 was hashed, it would only need to be a hashset, and it would be better because it would be able to handle internal-duplicates within the CollectionIn set, therefore:

```
var Set2 = new HashSet<string>();

//Prehash all values in one set (ideally the larger set)
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < CollectionIn2.Rows.Count; i2++)
{
    string value2 = CollectionIn2.Rows[i2].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower();

    if (Set2.Contains(value2))
        continue; //Duplicate value
    else
        Set2.Add(value2);
}

//Loop over the other set
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < CollectionIn.Rows.Count; i1++)
{
    string value1 = CollectionIn.Rows[i1].ItemArray[0].ToString().ToLower();

    if (Set2.Contains(value1) == false)
        continue;

    //Remove value1 when value1 == value2
    CollectionIn.Rows[i1].Delete();
}

CollectionIn.AcceptChanges(); //It's probably best to save changes last as a single call
```

This pattern would apply to many data set types (including List, array, and more). Of course, if you can write SQL for remote datasets on the same database, that's better.

If you love lambda functions, it should look something like this:

```
var alreadyInSet2 = new HashSet<string>(CollectionIn2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    .Select(x => x[0].ToString().ToLower()));

CollectionIn.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    .Where(y => alreadyInSet2.Contains(y[0].ToString().ToLower()) == false)
                    .ToList() //I think you technically need this before calling ForEach
                    .ForEach(y => y.Delete());

CollectionIn.AcceptChanges();
```

Also see: [With two very large lists/collections - how to detect and/or remove duplicates efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016873/with-two-very-large-lists-collections-how-to-detect-and-or-remove-duplicates-e/) - where more time/work can go into a broader arrange of answers and performance enhancements.

Comment: Can you explain why `AcceptChanges` is called on every single delete instead of hoisting it outside of the loop?  Also I would expect that to invalidate the indexes as the `Rows` collection has changed.

Comment: @Zer0 Because that's how the OPs code was, but that detail isn't part of the question. However, I have just updated my answer with a reversed strategy which is probably better, and I noticed that repeated call as you pointed out.

Comment: I asked because I would think that introduces a bug that boils down to modifying the collection while iterating over it.  Not merely performance.

Comment: Cheers, no probs.

Comment: +1 While more verbose, this is definitely a faster solution than my own, which only scales better the more rows there are.  Noting this for OPs sake.  Simplicity is probably better if the tables are small and performance impact negligable, but this is much better if they are big.

Comment: Hi, it gives me a compiler error "A new expression requires (), [], or {] after type. I googled and realized that maybe this line needs to be var Set2 = new HashSet<string>(); ?

Comment: @JAYY Sorry, I did this with notepad++ - I didn't test with a compiler. Fixed the object construction of Dictionary and Hashset.

Comment: @JAYY I would suggest you only need to test my last snippet of code.

Comment: I see. But i prefer the middle one cause it is easier to understand for someone like me that only has some java background :)

Comment: @JAYY I have updated all 3 snippets. They should all now be compilable.

Comment: Great thanks! But the result is still not correct. It's the same issue. It does not remove anything from collection1.

Comment: Is that the algorithm at fault or is it that the `Delete` function isn't working as you expect? Please put a breakpoint on the Delete function call and see if it's ever called.

Comment: I think that the algo is probably right but the Delete function isn't working for me. I'm using blue prism so i think it's probably the issue.

Comment: @JAYY I found a logic error in the second snippet. The `Contains` line now includes `== false`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173748/discussion-between-todd-and-jayy).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove duplicates using the [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) operator.

To remove duplicates from something like an IList<> you could do:

```
yourList.RemoveAll( yourList.Except( yourList.Distinct() ) );
```

Comment: Hi, so it's CollectionIn.RemoveAll(CollectionIn2.Except( CollectionIn.Distinct() ) ); ?
Just to clarify, the collectionIn has [A,B,C,D] and collectionIn2 has [A,B,C]. So this will help to remove the values (A,B,C) in collectionIn?

Comment: This is the wrong answer. This only compares the one set. The OP is referring to the comparison of two sets.

Comment: @Todd, without spoon feeding, the OP obviously has to combine the two sets into one for the above to work. It's to give him a clue.

Comment: @Fandango68 You may be right, but given what's in the OP post and how this article will be found and reused in the future, I don't think this kind of hinting is smiled upon in the stackoverflow community. It's just how it is.

Comment: @Todd care to point to a specific guideline that backs that? My understanding of SO is to both educate and help people with technical issues, not to spoon feed. Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183829/since-when-is-spoonfeeding-not-allowed" and the response from Bart "...You might want to slightly rephrase this. "Spoonfeeding" does not have a positive tone to it and it's certainly not what I would call "the best thing about this community". To me the word "spoonfeeding" indicates lazyness on behalf of the OP, something we surely discourage"

Comment: @Fandango68 I used the term "community" not "rules". Spoonfeeding is exactly what I personally use SO for. I copy-paste all the time in my line of work. I also answer my own questions for future use. I'm pretty sure in this situation your answer doesn't match the OP spec - it's pretty clearcut IMO.

Comment: @Fandango68 Have a look at this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016873/with-two-very-large-lists-collections-how-to-detect-and-or-remove-duplicates-e/51016874?noredirect=1#comment89026330_51016874], and see what I mean by "community". People like you genuinely try to help only to get "rejected".

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var row in CollectionIn.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Where(x => CollectionIn2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Any(y => y[0].ToString().ToLower() == x[0].ToString().ToLower())))
{
    row.Delete();
}
CollectionIn.AcceptChanges();
```

Not the best performance, but it works and is easy to read.

Also your code has a bug in it due to modifying the collections while iterating over them.

Comment: I think you are missing ( at line 3

Comment: @JAYY Corrected

Comment: Yeah, probably nice and simple when it's for only a few object sets to compare

Comment: @Todd Yup.  That's exactly why I noted the performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

It works and is easy to understand.

```
List<string> List1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
List<string> List2 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
List<string> ListTemp = new List<string>();

foreach (string str1 in List1)
{
     foreach (string str2 in List2)
     {
          if (str1 == str2)
          {
               ListTemp.Add(str1);
          }
     }
 }            

foreach (string temp in ListTemp)
{
     List1.Remove(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist2 = mylist2.Distinct().ToList();
mylist1.RemoveAll(item => mylist2.Contains(item));
```